# Extract the strings from list of dictionaries python

Tags: python, list, dictionary

I have below list of dictionaries.

```
self.local_devices_list =[
    {'type': '\x02', 'device_name': u'USB HID, ManufStr="", ProdStr="QWER1025", 
     SerialNum="ABCDEF0123456789", VendorID="0xa34", ProdID="0x4007"'},
    {'type': '\x02', 'device_name': u'USB HID, ManufStr="", ProdStr="ASDF452x", 
     SerialNum="ABCDEF0123456789", VendorID="0xa34", ProdID="0x4007"'}
]
```

I have extracted the value for key 'device_name' using the list comprehension

`device_names = [d["device_name"].encode("utf-8") for d in self.local_devices_list if "device_name" in d]`

I want to extract the information of device_name into separate strings like below

```
 1. ProdStr = QWER1025
 2. SerialNum = ABCDEF0123456789
 3. VendorID = 0xa34
 4. ProdID = 0x4007
```

Comment: you can replace the `=` with `:` and wrap the string in `{}` then you can use `ast.literal_eval` to turn it into a dict

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A regex can solve this dict easily.

```
import re
regex = re.compile(r'(\w+)="(\w*)"', flags=re.IGNORECASE)
for d in device_names:
    print(dict(regex.findall(d)))
```

> {'ManufStr': '', 'ProdStr': 'QWER1025', 'SerialNum':
>   'ABCDEF0123456789', 'VendorID': '0xa34', 'ProdID': '0x4007'}
>
> {'ManufStr': '', 'ProdStr': 'ASDF452x', 'SerialNum':
>   'ABCDEF0123456789', 'VendorID': '0xa34', 'ProdID': '0x4007'}

Answer (score 0):

You can use .values() and list(). values() will extract the values from the dictionary into a valueView, and list() will extract them to a list. If they are of string-type everything is good, otherwise you need to convert to string as you extract them from the list.

E.g:

```
ExtractedValues = list(self.local_devices_list.values())
str(ExtractedValues[0])
```

Answer (score 0):

You can split your variable like this :

```
device_names[0].split(', ')
```

This will give you a lit of items that you should be able to process.

```
['USB HID', 'ManufStr=""', 'ProdStr="QWER1025"', 'SerialNum="ABCDEF0123456789"', 'VendorID="0xa34"', 'ProdID="0x4007"']
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score -1):

You can join them:

```
information = [[" ".join(t) for t in d.items()] for d in self.local_devices_list]
```

Just add the filters you need into the lists comprehension.

Comment: But OP does not want everything. So `'type'` is irrelevant the way i understand it

Comment: @Ev.Kounis, sorry i do not understand your comment, could you explain?, ok, i understand now.

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre, much better indeed (only `t` not `*t`, dont need to unpack, since `join` takes an iterable), thanks :)

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre `join()` takes one argument only, right? So `join(*t)` will fail

Comment: notice that `'USB HID, ManufStr="", ProdStr="QWER1025", SerialNum="ABCDEF0123456789", VendorID="0xa34", ProdID="0x4007"'` is a string

Comment: @DanielSanchez Just `print(information)` and compare it to what OP wants as output. + he is probably using Python 2